# itextsharp file access after deployment

Tags: asp.net, iis, itext

Ok. I have a simple bit of code in asp.net using itextsharp. It works fine every time on the development box. I deploy it is IIS, and it works fine as well, at least for a while, then it throws an error that it cannot access the pdf file. I know the pdf is there because I looked, and also because the code is breaking at the itext reader object call, and not the system.io file check i do.

Strange thing is that if I use impersonation in the web.config as a server administrator account it works. Obviously I can't leave it like that. So, i tried impersonation as another account with admin rights to the whole web directory for the site, it worked all day, then it too stopped working. I tried app pool as a particular user as well, same thing, worked for while and then stopped working.

The only way to get it working again has been to put the impersonation back into the web.config using the server admin account. It then works again. It's driving me totally nuts. I've spent days on this. First I think I have it fixed and it works for hours and hours then it craps out again and I'm back at square.

Please help!

Here is my simple code for testing:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/intl/uploads/7752/7752-5280.pdf")))
        {
            Label1.Text = "File does exist";
          PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(Server.MapPath("~/intl/uploads/7752/7752-5280.pdf"));
            Label1.Text = reader.NumberOfPages.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "File does not exist";
        }

        //page count

    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: You do close the `PdfReader` right?

Comment: Yes. This was just the code so you follow what is going on.